# Exclude files from coverage calculation in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

Using SonarQube 5.3, maven and jacoco-maven-plugin (0.7.6.201602180812) with the following property in the pom

```
<sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/*.css</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
```

However, it does not seem to work. The css-files are still reported and it clutters up the graphs, see screen-shot below.

We do not wish to exclude the css-files completely by using the more general sonar.exclusions-property as we find it useful to see the technical debts of the css-files.

I've searched the archive for an answer, but there does not seem to be an answer to this particular issue. And I did not find any help in  http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus either. Would be grateful for any hints!

[custom.css with 0% coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57rdx.png)

Comment: what happens when you try with a sonar.coverage.exclusions = **/* (it should exclude every file)?
what happens when you update the settings via the UI as told in the "Narrowing the Focus" documentation?

Comment: I meant `**/*` for the property

Comment: How is it possible you get coverage on your CSS files? I have just tested with CSS plugin 1.8 and there is no coverage reported (SonarQube 5.5).

Comment: @Teryk-SonarSourceTeam: excluding with `**/*` gives "This component does not have coverage details."

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam: I don't know. That's what I'm asking as well :-) It's clearly there: http://i.stack.imgur.com/57rdx.png

Comment: @Teryk-SonarSourceTeam: updating the settings via the UI yields the same result as setting via the pom

Comment: Did you have an anwsers ? I have the same issue ...

Comment: try sonar.exclusions maybe...